# Celery not executing new tasks if redis lost connection is restablished

Tags: python, python-3.x, redis, celery

I have a Celery worker configured to connect to redis as follows:

```
 celery_app_site24x7 = Celery('monitoringExterne.celerys.site24x7',
                             broker=settings.REDIS['broker'], backend=settings.REDIS['backend'])

celery_app_site24x7.conf.broker_transport_options = {
    'visibility_timeout': 36000
}

celery_app_site24x7.conf.socket_timeout = 300
celery_app_site24x7.conf.broker_connection_max_retries = None
celery_app_site24x7.config_from_object('django.conf:settings')
celery_app_site24x7.autodiscover_tasks(lambda: settings.INSTALLED_APPS)
```

The issue is that if Redis is down and the connection is restablished new tasks added in the queue are not executed:

```
[2020-01-13 10:10:14,517: ERROR/MainProcess] consumer: Cannot connect to redis://xxx.xxx.xxx.xx:6380/10: Error while reading from socket: ('Connection closed by server.',).
Trying again in 2.00 seconds...

[2020-01-13 10:10:16,590: INFO/MainProcess] Connected to redis://xxx.xxx.xxx.xx:6380/10
[2020-01-13 10:10:16,699: INFO/MainProcess] mingle: searching for neighbors
[2020-01-13 10:10:17,766: INFO/MainProcess] mingle: all alone
```

I have manually called a celery task through the django shell as follows:

> celery_tasks.site24x7.test.delay()

It returns me the Async task ID but the worker doesnot process this task.

```
<AsyncResult:ff634b85-edb5-44d4-bdb1-17a220761fcc>
```

If I continue to launch the task as delay the queue keeps incrementing:

```
127.0.0.1:6379[10]> llen site24x7
(integer) 4
127.0.0.1:6379[10]> llen site24x7
(integer) 5
```

Below are the output of the celery status and inspect

> $ celery -A monitoringExterne --app=monitoringExterne.celerys.site24x7
>
> status Error: No nodes replied within time constraint.
>
> $ celery -A monitoringExterne --app=monitoringExterne.celerys.site24x7 inspect active
>
> Error: No nodes replied within time constraint.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your workers are not subscribed to the `site24x7` queue, then the number of tasks in that queue will keep increasing... Try to run the work with somwething like: `celery -A monitoringExterne.celerys.site24x7 -Q site24x7 -l info`

Also, keep in mind that `-A` and `--app` are the same flag, you should not use both.

If you are getting the `No nodes replied within time constraint` output, that means you have no Celery workers active in your cluster, which also could be the reason why the number of tasks is increasing in that queue - there are no workers to execute them!

Comment: Thank you for your feedback. Well task are being processed but only stop executing new task if redis is down then up again. When I start my celery worker i start it as follows: `celery -A monitoringExterne worker --app=monitoringExterne.celerys.site24x7 -n site24x7.site24x7 -Q site24x7 --loglevel=DEBUG` i'll try to launch it without specifying `-A monitoringExterne` and see what is the outcome.

Comment: Hi @KheshavSewnundun, have you managed to solve the problem?

Comment: Hello @Geku unfortunately no. We have switched from redis to Rabbitmq and the issue is less frequent.

Comment: Thanks for the update @KheshavSewnundun! I'm currently trying to fix it but without success. Gonna switch to Rabbitmq too.

Answer (score 1):

There appears to be an issue with Celery on Redis that may actually be causing this:

[Worker stops consuming tasks after redis reconnection](https://github.com/celery/celery/issues/8030)